# Make animated collapsible card component, with initial props to show or hide

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

**Background**

Using React Native I was able to make collapsible card component. On Icon click the card slides up hiding its content, or expands showing its content. I would think setting the default value would be as easy as setting expanded to false or true, but I think the problem here is that when it is toggled an animation is triggered which changes the height of the card.

**Example**

```js
class CardCollapsible extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: props.title,
      expanded: true,
      animation: new Animated.Value(),
      iconExpand: "keyboard-arrow-down",
    };
  }

  _setMaxHeight(event){
      this.setState({
          maxHeight   : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
      });
  }

  _setMinHeight(event){
      this.setState({
          minHeight   : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
      });

      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle(){
    let initialValue    = this.state.expanded? this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight : this.state.minHeight,
        finalValue      = this.state.expanded? this.state.minHeight : this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight;

    this.setState({
      expanded : !this.state.expanded
    });

    if (this.state.iconExpand === "keyboard-arrow-up") {
      this.setState({
        iconExpand : "keyboard-arrow-down"
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        iconExpand : "keyboard-arrow-up"
      })
    }
    this.state.animation.setValue(initialValue);
    Animated.spring( this.state.animation, {
        toValue: finalValue
      }
    ).start();
  }

  render(){

    return (
      <Animated.View style={[styles.container,{height: this.state.animation}]}>
          <View style={styles.titleContainer} onLayout={this._setMinHeight.bind(this)}>
            <CardTitle>{this.state.title}</CardTitle>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={this.toggle}
              underlayColor="#f1f1f1">
              <Icon
                name={this.state.iconExpand}
                style={{ fontSize: 30 }}/>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
          <Separator />
          <View style={styles.card} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin:10,
    overflow:'hidden'
    },
  titleContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
    },
  card: {
    padding: 10
  }
});

export { CardCollapsible };
```

**Open**

[image]

Closed

[image]

**Question**

My goal is to allow a person calling the component to set the initial state of the component to expanded or open. But when I try changing the expanded state to `false` it does not render closed.

How would I go about allowing the user calling the component to select whether it is expanded or closed on initial component render?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made a brand new one for you. Simple and works fine.

**Note: no `state` required for this component. fewer state, better performance.**

Maybe you could modify your own style on top of this =)

```js
class Card extends Component {
    anime = {
        height: new Animated.Value(),
        expanded: false,
        contentHeight: 0,
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._initContentHeight = this._initContentHeight.bind(this);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

        this.anime.expanded = props.expanded;
    }

    _initContentHeight(evt) {
        if (this.anime.contentHeight>0) return;
        this.anime.contentHeight = evt.nativeEvent.layout.height;
        this.anime.height.setValue(this.anime.expanded ? this._getMaxValue() : this._getMinValue() );
    }

    _getMaxValue() { return this.anime.contentHeight };
    _getMinValue() { return 0 };

    toggle() {
        Animated.timing(this.anime.height, {
            toValue: this.anime.expanded ? this._getMinValue() : this._getMaxValue(),
            duration: 300,
        }).start();
        this.anime.expanded = !this.anime.expanded;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                <View style={styles.title}>
                    <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.toggle}>
                        <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>

                <Animated.View style={[styles.content, { height: this.anime.height }]} onLayout={this._initContentHeight}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
<Card title='Customized Card 1' expanded={false}>
    <Text>Hello, this is first line.</Text>
    <Text>Hello, this is second line.</Text>
    <Text>Hello, this is third line.</Text>
</Card>
```

Visual result: (only second card start with `expanded={true}`, others with `expanded={false}`)

[image]

Comment: So should I be able to set the initial value now when the component is called like this, <CardCollapsible expanded={true} title="A Panel with short content text">
          <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</Text>
        </CardCollapsible>

Comment: @wuno yes it is. this way you can pass `expanded` as a prop into `<CardCollapsible>`.

Comment: Well that is letting me pass the value with props. But it is still giving me the same problem as before. It is setting the value but not triggering the animation. So it makes me click it twice the first time when i set it to be closed on load. Because the value is opposite but the card is showing. So it does not close, The problem here is that when I set the value to false the card still loads initially open.

Comment: you want to trigger the closing animation when set initial `expanded={false}` ?

Comment: No, I just want it to be closed on page load. If they person calling the component sets the initial value to close. But what I am saying is, if I change the value to true, or false, it is still open when the component loads.

Comment: when expand => false only the container animate height to zero and children stay visible? anyone know why this happens?

Comment: @mahmoud I need more info to possibly tell why that happened, code of children could helps.

Comment: @Val It seems like the children still visible on the screen on the ios emulator, but on the android phone, it works fine.

Comment: @Val Can you please tell me,how to achieve, if one card is expanded, all other cards should be collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The expanded value 'true/false' should be passed from the calling component and you need to use this value to expand/collapse your component. I can't see your have used 'expanded' inside render method. You should do like this:

```
 { this.props.expanded && <View style={styles.card} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
            {this.props.children}
          </View> }
```

Comment: but setting the value to false is not going to just make the component hide that section. Did you test this? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

i follow step on some blog then i have same condition with it. so i made a changes after clue from others here. my post maybe is to late. but i wish will be help others.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'
import styles from './styles' //put styles from another file

class PanelExpanding extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      expanded: false, //step 1 
      animation: new Animated.Value()
    }

    this.icons = {
      'up': require('../../..assets/images/up.png'),
      'down': require('../../../assets/images/down.png')
    }
  }

  toggle(){
    let finalValue    = this.state.expanded? this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight : this.state.minHeight,
        initialValue  = this.state.expanded? this.state.minHeight : this.state.maxHeight + this.state.minHeight;
    //step 2, this needed, if we use !this.state.expanded i don't know how it wont changes at first
    if(this.state.expanded === true){
      return this.setState({ expanded : false })
    } else {
      return this.setState({ expanded : true })
    }
    this.state.animation.setValue(initialValue);
    Animated.spring(
        this.state.animation,
        { toValue: finalValue }
    ).start();
  }


  _setMinHeight(event){
    this.setState({
        minHeight : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
  }

  _setMaxHeight(event){
    this.setState({
        maxHeight : event.nativeEvent.layout.height
    });
  }


  render(){
    let icon = this.icons['down'],
        textSwap = 'SHOWMORE'

    if(this.state.expanded){
      icon = this.icons['up'],
      textSwap = 'SHOWLESS'
    }

    return (
      <Animated.View
            style={[styles.containerPanel,{height: this.state.animation}]} >
        <View>
          <View style={styles.titleContainer} onLayout={this._setMinHeight.bind(this)}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.button}
                  onPress={this.toggle.bind(this)} >
                  <Text style={styles.textShow}>{textSwap}</Text>
                  <Image
                      style={styles.buttonImage}
                      source={icon} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          //step 3, add this to initial when first render is false
          {this.state.expanded && <View style={styles.body} onLayout={this._setMaxHeight.bind(this)}>
            <Text>
              {this.props.children}
            </Text>
          </View>}
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}

export default PanelExpanding
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// With hooks for rn


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Image,
    StyleSheet
  } from 'react-native'
  import styles from '../../assets/styles' 
  const usePanelExpanding = (props) => {


    let icons = {
        'up': require('../../images/formicons/icons/close.png'),
        'down': require('../../images/formicons/icons/disclosure.png')
      }

      const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
      const [iconShow, setIconShow] = useState('up');
      const [textSwap, setTextSwap] = useState('Show more...');


      useEffect(
        () => {
          expanded ? setIconShow('up') : setIconShow('down')
          expanded ? setTextSwap('Show less') : setTextSwap('Show more ...')
        },
        [expanded]
      );

      const toggle = () =>{
        setExpanded(!expanded)
      }

      const panel = (<View>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer} >
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={toggle} >
                <Image
                    style={styles.buttonImage}
                    source={icons[iconShow]} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        {expanded && <View style={styles.mainPageFull} >
            {props}
        </View>
      }
      </View>)
      return {
        panel,
        toggle
      }
  }
  export default usePanelExpanding


// How to use it from a parent function

 const expandingBioObject = usePanelExpanding(<Text>{profile.bio}</Text>)
<Card title="Biography" containerStyle={styles.CardContainerBio}>
      {expandingBioObject.panel}
      </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [react-native-collapsible-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view).
you can pass it `expanded` property which allows you to fully control the collapsible state by other components. 
you can also leave him self-controlled but pass `initExpanded` which allows you to choose what is the initial state of the collapsible.