# React Native - Hide and Show Component on Button Click with Animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-animated

Friend I have issue to hide and show at runtime when user click on the button the the component (View) have to hide and again click on the button it should be show.

MYCODE :

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible : false,
    };
  }

callFunc(){
   if(this.isModalVisible){
     this.setState({isModalVisible:false});
   }else{
     this.setState({isModalVisible:true});
   }
}

render() {
    return (

      <View style = {styles.companyScroll}>
         <Button
          onPress={this.callFunc}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
         />

        {this.state.isModalVisible &&  <Picker style ={{backgroundColor : 'white'}}
                selectedValue={this.state.language}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
                <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
                <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
              </Picker>

      </View>
   )
}
```

**I want to like below image.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also use `this.state.isModalVisible` instead of `this.isModalVisible` from `callFunc()`.

Comment: Thanks. Now working. But want with animation. any idea.

Comment: what kind of animation, opacity or dropdown or else?

Comment: You should use Animated component. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html

Answer (score 2):

You missed the function bind:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.callFunc = this.callFunc.bind(this);
    ...
}
```

without it, `callFunc` will not be in the scope of `this` object and have no access to its state.

And as @AlexanderIgnácz said, there's a typo there - should change `this.isModalVisible` into `this.state.isModalVisible`. maybe late, but also I was going to say, and for the purpose to complete this answer.

Comment: I will try but not working. the function is called and only open the view, But it's not hidden on second tap.

Comment: about animation, check my another answer about card component show & hide. it might be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428351/681830

Comment: uh, contact me for what? can we just question / answer right here?

Comment: ask more questions, I'll do my best to give answer to you. not prefer to answer privately, that way others cannot get helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150909/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-val).

Comment: Please help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658124/checked-unchecked-doesnt-working-in-listview-in-react-native

Comment: please have solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551462/how-to-drag-and-drop-with-multiple-view-in-react-native

Comment: can you help me :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904949/how-to-set-background-image-of-drawernavigator-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

in constructor add

```
this.callFunc = this.callFunc.bind(this);
```

in onPress replace with

```
{()=>{ this.callFunc(); }
```

You can see here an litte example:

https://snack.expo.io/HkxpgSlPZ

@+

Comment: You shouldn't write arrow functions inside your `render` function, otherwise, a new arrow function will be allocated each time the render function is called. Better implementation : create a local arrow function in your component class, and reference it into your `onPress` prop.

Comment: Here's a source that explains that : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36

Answer (score 0):

use [react-native-collapsible-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view).
It seems to serve exactly your needs.