# Getting NaN when trying to use new Animated.Value() in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to implement a collapsible card in React Native, and regardless of the implementation I use, keep getting the same error:

*[555,"RCTView",211,{"onLayout":true,"height":"<< NaN>>"}] is not usable as a native method argument*

The problem lies in using `new Animated.Value()`, when I initialize it with a value, say `new Animated.Value(100)`, the error goes away and the functionality works, but the maximum height of is that constant I put in, which is not what I want. So, it seems not passing any values to Animated.Value has it return NaN.

I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior, but I'm assuming it is not as my code is almost exactly the same as here: [Make animated collapsible card component, with initial props to show or hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428284/make-animated-collapsible-card-component-with-initial-props-to-show-or-hide)

I will paste my code regardless:

Card.js:

```
import {Text, View, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, Animated} from 'react-native'

export default class Card extends React.Component{
  anime = {
      height: new Animated.Value(),
      expanded: false,
      contentHeight: 0,
  }

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this._initContentHeight = this._initContentHeight.bind(this);
      this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);

      this.anime.expanded = props.expanded;
  }

  _initContentHeight(evt) {
      if (this.anime.contentHeight>0) return;
      this.anime.contentHeight = evt.nativeEvent.layout.height;
      this.anime.height.setValue(this.anime.expanded ? this._getMaxValue() : this._getMinValue() );
  }

  _getMaxValue() { return this.anime.contentHeight };
  _getMinValue() { return 0 };

  toggle() {
      Animated.timing(this.anime.height, {
          toValue: this.anime.expanded ? this._getMinValue() : this._getMaxValue(),
          duration: 300,
      }).start();
      this.anime.expanded = !this.anime.expanded;
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <View style={styles.title}>
                  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.toggle}>
                      <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
                  </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>

              <Animated.View style={[styles.content, { height: this.anime.height }]} onLayout={this._initContentHeight}>
                  {this.props.children}
              </Animated.View>
          </View>
      );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin:10,
    overflow:'hidden'
    },
  titleContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
    },
  card: {
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

SearchDisplay.js:

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from '../components/Panel';

export default class SearchDisplay extends React.Component {
render (){
    return (
      <Card title='Customized Card 1' expanded={false}>
                <Text>Hello, this is first line.</Text>
                <Text>Hello, this is second line.</Text>
                <Text>Hello, this is third line.</Text>
            </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Apologies in advance if it's something really obvious that I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

As a initial value give it a 0. Then you can try to get the height of animated.view component and set it in a value in state.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout

But I'm not sure you can or not place it in a Animated.Value(). Who knows, it may works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Animated.Value should be initialized with some initial value like 0 or else you can directly use 0 as your initial height.

Comment: I'm having this error despite setting initial value as well

Answer (score -2):

NAN means you calculating a mathematic operation but you are passing non-integer value in your functionality